# stm32 HAL CAN FD with auto-retransmission without freezing?

Tags: stm32, can-bus, stm32cubeide, cmsis

I am trying to get the STM32 hal_fdcan.c library to properly send out classical CAN signals with accurate intervals. With auto-retransmission enabled this works quite well. However when this is enabled the system freezes if there are no receiver nodes available. Since it just tries to send the CAN message over and over until a node receives it.

I am successfully queuing messages so they are all being sent properly but one of the messages I send has a high can id so is being sent with low priority and therefore isn't always sent every intervall unless auto-retransmission is enabled.

Is it possible to implement a timeout if a message isn't sent after a certain amount of time? Or is there some other way to implement a failsafe so that if no CAN nodes are available the system is able to control GPIOs or continue running?

Below are my CAN-FD init settings

```
  hfdcan2.Instance = FDCAN2;
  hfdcan2.Init.ClockDivider = FDCAN_CLOCK_DIV1;
  hfdcan2.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;
  hfdcan2.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hfdcan2.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;
  hfdcan2.Init.TransmitPause = ENABLE;
  hfdcan2.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;
  hfdcan2.Init.NominalPrescaler = 1;
  hfdcan2.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 24;
  hfdcan2.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 119;
  hfdcan2.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 24;
  hfdcan2.Init.DataPrescaler = 4;
  hfdcan2.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 6;
  hfdcan2.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 29;
  hfdcan2.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 6;
  hfdcan2.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan2.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;
  hfdcan2.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;
```

I have tried looking into different functions in the hal_fdcan.c file but there doesn't seem to be any timeout function. I have tried using TransmitPause but to no avail